# Why are the derivatives of $\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}$ and $\frac{-x}{x^2+x+1}$ the same?

Tags: derivatives

> Why are the derivatives of these functions the same?
> $$\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1} \qquad\qquad \frac{-x}{x^2+x+1}$$

[original exercise text (See part (e).)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFs7y.png)

I have tried to answer this question and consulted the answer booklet but this did not make much sense. Would someone be able to simplify or elaborate further? Thank you :)

The answer guide said the derivates are the same as differ at most by an additive constant.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: To check that the two expressions differ by a constant, subtract the second expression from the first and see what you get.

Comment: Consider what it means for two functions to have equal derivatives. Or vice versa, consider what distinguishes the possible antiderivatives of a function.

Comment: Remember that $\frac{d}{dx}$ is a linear operator as well

Comment: Because if $f(x)-g(x)=Constant$ then........(You do know what).

Comment: Add "1" to the expression on the right, and see what it looks like when you put it over the same denominator.

Answer (score 3):

$$
{d\over dx} (f(x)+1)={df\over dx}+{d1\over dx}={df\over dx}
$$
so we can add $1$ to a function and the derivative of the sum is the same as the derivative of the function. So
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{-x}{x^2+x+1}+1
&=\frac{-x}{x^2+x+1}+\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2+x+1}\\
&={x^2+x+1-x\over x^2+x+1}\\
&={x^2+1\over x^2+x+1}\\
\end{align}
$$